# Pulling non-transparent areas to the center of the transparent areas in an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am making an image processing project which has a few steps and stuck in one of them. Here is the thing; I have segmented an image and subtract the foreground from background. Now, I need to fill the background.

So far, I have tried the inpainting algorithms. They don't work in my case because my background images haven't at least 40% of them. I mean they fail when they are trying the complete 40% of an image. (By the way, these images have given bad results even in the Photoshop with content-aware tool.)

Anyway, I've given up trying inpainting and decided something else. In my project, I don't need to complete 100% of my background. I want to illustrate my solution;

[image]

As you see in the image above, I want to pull the image to the black area (which is transparent) with minimum corruption. Any MATLAB code samples, technique, keyword and approach would be great. If you need further explanation, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two crude ways to fill the hole:

use [`roifill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifill.html): this fills gaps in 2d image preserving image smoothness.

Alteratively, you can use [`bwdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) to compute the nearest neighbor of each black pixel and assign it to its nearest neighbor's color:

```
[~, nnIdx] = bwdist( bw );
fillImg(bw) = IMG(bw);
```

although this code snippet works only for gray images, it is quite trivial to extend it to RGB color images.

Comment: bwdist can be work Shai but roifill doesn't give acceptable results. Well, I'll keep in mind. Do you know any code snippet that pulls/extends a point to another point in an image?

Comment: That's a pretty large hole to fill with a lot of edges, I highly doubt that there is any way to get an acceptable result without special casing for this image.

Comment: @Noremac You were right. That's a very large - almost 40% of the image- hole. Shai's suggestions haven't given any promising result. Most of the cases are unfortunately in this form. Photoshop's content aware fill tool has even failed. I changed my perspective and created a solution. I'm shifting the pixels to the hole with a dynamic rate. I mean the closest pixels to the hole shift less, the others shift more. Finally I've applied custom 8-neighbor mean filter. Process time almost 2 seconds and this approach given promising results surprisingly with my case.